# Issue with Inno Setup and Disk Spanning

Tags: inno-setup

I have a small issue with Inno Setup and its diskspanning option.

I'm only using it to get the ultra compression and being able to generate a very small setup executable that won't trigger an antivirus for a long time.
So, I'm using ISTool to generate a very basic script and the only options I altered were the compression, the fact that I didn't want one big executable and being able to span the files on multiple DVDs.

It works fine up until I create the DVDs.
At the very end of the install process, after all the files have been extracted, it crashes with a c0000006 error.
I made another try, tweaking the diskspanning option (telling IS that I'm going to have 4 1Gb files per disk), but it also crashes (without any specific error).

The "c0000006" error seems to be related to the fact that the setup cannot find its "setup.exe", but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Do you use SolidCompression=True for your setup? In case of multi-part installer this parameter should be set to False. I assume that when you try to install from HDD, where all BINa are in the very same folder as setup.exe there is no Error raised?

Comment: Yes, that option is set to true and it works fine when all the files are in the same folder. I'll make another try, thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 1):

Long after the original question, but for anyone with a similar issue. If you're using DiskSpanning, set UseSetupLdr=yes.
From the Inno doc for UseSetupLdr: "Do not use UseSetupLdr=no on an installation which uses disk spanning (DiskSpanning=yes). When UseSetupLdr is yes, the setup program is copied to and run from the user's TEMP directory. This does not happen when UseSetupLdr is no, and could result in errors if **Windows tries to locate the setup.exe file on the disk and can't find it because a different disk is in the drive**."